# the input field size in HTML

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML, I have a part of code that generate a label,  it works fine but I do habe a problem with the label size,`<label for="voltage-amount;">V</label>`  I tried to use `display:inline-block` like :

```
`<label for="voltage-amount;"display:inline-block>V</label>`
```

but it didn't change anything,  here is the code that I'm working on:

```
    <div id="voltage-box" class="box">
    <p>voltage limit:</p>
    <input name="aoutu" type="text" id="voltage-amount"  class="slicknumber" value="<%= format("%0.3f",channel.valueor 0)%>"/>
    <label for="voltage-amount;">V</label><div id="voltage"></div>
</div>
```

an idea how can I do this, thanks !

**UPDATE**

thanks for your helps here is what I've done now :

```
    <div id="voltage-box" class="box">
    <p>voltage limit:</p>
    <input name="aoutu" type="text" id="voltage-amount"  class="slicknumber" value="<%= format("%0.3f",channel.aoutu or 0)%>"/>
    <label for="voltage-amount" style="display:inline-block">V</label> <div id="voltage"></div>
</div>
```

and  I still don't get a "bigger" size of the label :

[image: label]

the label should show at the least enough please for 6 digits which's not the case !  did I  do something wrong here  ?

**2nd Update **

the code looks like :

```
<input name="aoutu" type="text" id="voltage-amount"  class="slicknumber" style="display: inline-block; width: 300px" value="<%= format("%0.3f",channel.aoutu or 0)%>"/>
```

and still no change! thanks again your help

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: you have to use style="display:inline-block".

Comment: Are trying to make larger Input field to show at least 6 digits on that, or wanted to make the label "V" bigger??

Comment: You should edit the question (and it title) so that it corresponds to the real problem. It is the input field you want to size, not the label!

Comment: The code posted does not produce the rendering shown. The problem is caused by something that is not shown in the question at all.

Comment: @Jukka.Korpela I've change the title, but the code works fine now, thanks to Aminul answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted this one...

```
<input name="aoutu" type="text" id="voltage-amount"  class="slicknumber" style="display:inline-block" value="<%= format("%0.3f",channel.aoutu or 0)%>"/>
```

If this is not satisfactory then you can add CSS `width` to expand it more. Example

```
style="display: inline-block; width: 30px"
```

Comment: @it Aminul I tried it the field still have the same size :\

Comment: yeah I copied and pasted it and nothing changed !

Comment: that was an Example, increase the value of width, try 100px or 200px, you will see the change

Comment: sorry but still no change, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues here:

```
<label for="voltage-amount" style="display:inline-block">V</label>
```

Remove the `;` character in the `for` attribute and wrap the `display` directive into a `style` attribute if you want it to work.

Otherwise, what is the problem with the size`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to add some style to the label for that you've to specify it in style property:

```
<label for="voltage-amount" style="display:inline-block">V</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<label for="voltage-amount;"display:inline-block>V</label>
```

this is wrong use of inline styles

```
<label for="voltage-amount;" style="display:inline-block">V</label>
```

and if you wants to work on font size do something like this

```
<label for="voltage-amount;" style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px">V</label>
```

or any size that you wants